# Not getting desired result when using synchronized keyword in Java multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have two files, `App.java` and `Runner.java`

`App.java` -->

```
public class App {
    private static Thread thread1 = new Runner(1);
    private static Thread thread2 = new Runner(2);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();

        System.out.printf("Count = %d\n", Runner.getCount());
    }
}
```

`Runner.java` -->

```
public class Runner extends Thread {
    private volatile static int count = 0;
    private int option = 0;

    private synchronized void increment() {
        count++;
    }

    private synchronized void decrement() {
        count--;
    }

    public Runner(int option) {
        this.option = option;
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        switch (option) {
            case 1:
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
                    increment();
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
                    decrement();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to create two `threads` from `main` `thread` and access a common `variable` from both the threads where both the `threads` will manipulate this common `variable` at the same time.

I am trying to create a demo for implementation for the `synchronized` keyword.

In my example, in `Runner.java` -

I am making `Runner` `class` a `child` class of `Thread` using `extends` `keyword` and `overriding` the `run()` `method` in body.

Next, I am using a `constructor` to get an `option` and running the respective code in `run()` method in a `switch - case` `block`. The common variable is `count` which is `static` with initial value 0.

There are two `methods`, both use the `synchronized` `keyword` - `increment()` and `decrement()` which increase and decrease the value of count by 1 respectively.

For `option 1` `run()` method uses a `for loop` to run `increment()` 10,000 times.
For `option 2` `run()` method uses a `for loop` to run `decrement()` 10,000 times.

As such the end value of `count` should be 0.

In `App.java` -

I am creating two `threads` - `thread1`, `thread2` which are instances of `Runner class` and passing `constructor` `argument` 1 and 2 respectively.

I am running the two `threads` using `thread.start()` and waiting for completion of the two `threads` using `thread.join()`

Now, I am printing the value of `count`. The value is expected to be 0. But it is not. In each execution it is near to 0 but not 0.

So, where am I going wrong and how to correct my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` is static meaning there is only one such variable.
Both `increment` and `decrement` are not static which means they are synchronized on `this` - that is two separate `Runner` instances.

Make those method static:

```
private synchronized static void increment() {
    count++;
}

private synchronized static void decrement() {
    count--;
}
```

or use explicit mutex object:

```
private static int count = 0;
private static Object mutex = new Object;

private int option = 0;

private void increment() {
    synchronized (mutex) {
        count++;
    }
}

private void decrement() {
    synchronized (mutex) {
        count--;
    }
}
```